# Git Bash ... Angular ... ng serve ... Cannot find module xxxxx\Git\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

Tags: angular, module, command-line-interface, git-bash

Using ***Git Bash*** to run "***ng serve***" and started getting this error:

```
$ ng s
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I've been using "ng serve" for thousands times and it was nothing like this. For months it was OK. I don't even know what can be the reason of this error. But seems like it's trying to look for Angular modules in the folder of Git, where it's totally shouldn't exist at all. I didn't update Git Bash. So, I don't know why Git Bash trying to look for "ng" in Git folder. Seems like the correct folder is "**AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin**"

So, does someone know how to make Git Bash work correctly?

It's all about Git Bash, because basic Windows Terminal works fine with "ng serve".

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? I am stuck because of the same issue for weeks now. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with the help from [github](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/530) using symlink
 Run command below in your cmd at administrator mode

```
C:\Program Files\Git>mklink /D node_modules %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

just in case you want to remove the symlink from it

```
C:\Program Files\Git>rmdir node_module
```